# TFS2013 builds config file

Tags: config, nightly-build

I need to setup some setting in a configuration file of the nightly build done my our Build Server (Team Foundation Server 2013). It is a 'runtime > Bindingredirect' setting. This should be done in the app.config file. But the nightly build of a class library does not have a config file. How do i change the config of the build of TFS.

Is there a config file for the build agent/controller? And if there is, where can i find this?
Or do I need to edit the build template?

**Edit:** I have a class library that references System.Web.Mvc, and the class library (dll) is used in multiple MVC websites. The web.config of those websites have a bindingredirect (I need this to make the website work properly). Now the class library is part of our nightly build. The class library is part of another solution than the websites.

The TFS build (nighly build) fails every night because of the 'missing bindingredirect'. Because the only way to get the bindingredirect to work is in a config file, i need to change the config file of the nightly build process, because a class library does not have a config file.

Comment: It is not clear: you want to edit a config file belonging to build artifacts? Or you need to set the config of some tool run during the build?

Comment: Hi Giulio, i added some more information to the question